# Pandas: grouby and sort (ascending and descending mixed)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How do we group a dataframe based on a column, generate values (say mean) based on another column and finally sort these such that the overall grouping is sorted based on mean values(descending) and within the groups sorted based on mean(descending) however for equal values sort alphabetical(ascending) based on the first grouped by column?
Eg.: Assume we have a dataframe of participant names and their scores on different activities. I want to first groupby the participant name, generate mean values of the scores. Sort this group descending based on the mean values. For cases where mean values are equal, sort ascending based on their names.

`DF:
name    task    score
User1   task1   3
User2   task2   8
User3   task3   7
User4   task4   7
User5   task5   8
User6   task6   8
User7   task7   2
User8   task8   7
User9   task9   6
User10  task10  1
User1   task11  5
User2   task12  7
User3   task13  1
User4   task14  8
User5   task15  0
User6   task16  2
User7   task17  8
User8   task18  1
User9   task19  3
User10  task20  4`

`Out:
Name    mean_score
User2   7.5
User4   7.5
User6   5
User7   5
User9   4.5
User1   4
User3   4
User5   4
User8   4
User10  2.5`

Note: The generated mean scores are sorted descending, for equal values user names sorted alphabetically ascending

My code:

`top = df_tasks.groupby(['name'],as_index=False)['score'].mean().sort_values(by=['score'],axis=0,ascending=False,inplace=False)`

gives me the below:

`name   mean_score
User2   7.5
User4   7.5
User7   5
User6   5
User9   4.5
User8   4
User3   4
User1   4
User5   4
User10  2.5`

sorting this output on name affects the score based sorting. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
df['mean_score'] = df.groupby('name').score.mean().reset_index(drop=True)

df.sort_values(by=['mean_score'])
```